# php echo add text end of the line

Tags: php, echo

```
foreach($divs as $element)
{
$img = $element->find('a', 0)->href.'<br>';
$img = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/", $img);

echo $img."/mqdefault.jpg";

}
```

Now output is :

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/UYkHcfrxxtk
/mqdefault.jpghttp://img.youtube.com/vi/ZgjaveCUsSg
/mqdefault.jpghttp://img.youtube.com/vi/TFVbehwl1Ns
/mqdefault.jpg
```

I want like this each img:

```
  http://img.youtube.com/vi/UYkHcfrxxtk/mqdefault.jpg
```

How can get fix this? i used simple html dom.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this.

remove `.'<br>'` from end of `$img = $element->find('a', 0)->href.'<br>';` then add it to `echo $img."/mqdefault.jpg";`

`<br>` in html mean newline

```
$img = $element->find('a', 0)->href;
$img = str_replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "http://img.youtube.com/vi/", $img);

echo $img."/mqdefault.jpg".'<br>';
```

Comment: are you remove `.'<br>'` from end of `$img = $element->find('a', 0)->href;`

Answer (score 0):

`echo $img."/mqdefault.jpg<br/>";`

But if you are trying to make image elements on a page:

```
echo "<img src='".$img."' /><br/>";
```